# Difference between okhttp client timeouts and apache timeouts

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp, apache-httpcomponents

In the past I used the http client of apache. I had settings for :

- Connection Request timeout
- Connect timeout
- Read/socket timeout
- ConnectionPool size

I am migrating to the OkHttp client and it has different timeouts:

- connect-timeout
- call-timeout
- read-timeout
- write-timeout
- max-idle-connections (connection pool setting)
- keep-alive-duration-minutes (connection pool setting)

How do they map to each other?

Regards,

Rick

Answer (score 3):

Extracting from the excellent article written on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-timeouts), here are a few details:

1. Connect Timeout:

   A connect timeout defines a **time period in which our client should establish a connection with a target host.**
   By default, for the `OkHttpClient`, this timeout is set to 10 seconds.

   However, we can easily change its value using the `OkHttpClient.Builder#connectTimeout` method. A value of zero means no timeout at all.

   Let's now see how to build and use an `OkHttpClient` with a custom connection timeout:

   ```
   @Test
   public void whenConnectTimeoutExceeded_thenSocketTimeoutException() {
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         .build();

       Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url("http://203.0.113.1") // non routable address
         .build();

       Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> client.newCall(request).execute());

       assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(SocketTimeoutException.class);
   }
   ```

   The above example shows that the client throws a `SocketTimeoutException` when the connection attempt exceeds the configured timeout.
2. Call Timeout:

   A call timeout is a bit different than the connect, read and write timeouts we already discussed. **It defines a time limit for a complete HTTP call**. This includes resolving DNS, connecting, writing the request body, server processing, as well as reading the response body. Unlike other timeouts, **it's default value is set to zero which implies no timeout**. But of course, we can configure a custom value using `OkHttpClient.Builder#callTimeout` method.

   Let's see a practical usage example:

   ```
   @Test
   public void whenCallTimeoutExceeded_thenInterruptedIOException() {
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .callTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .build();

       Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url("https://httpbin.org/delay/2")
         .build();

       Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> client.newCall(request).execute());

       assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(InterruptedIOException.class);
   }
   ```
3. Read Timeout:

   A read timeout is applied from the moment the connection between a client and a target host has been successfully established.

   It defines a **maximum time of inactivity between two data packets when waiting for the server's response**.

   The default timeout of 10 seconds can be changed using `OkHttpClient.Builder#readTimeout`. Analogously as for the connect timeout, a zero value indicates no timeout.

   Let's now see how to configure a custom read timeout in practice:

   ```
   @Test
   public void whenReadTimeoutExceeded_thenSocketTimeoutException() {
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         .build();

       Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url("https://httpbin.org/delay/2") // 2-second response time
         .build();

       Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> client.newCall(request).execute());

       assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(SocketTimeoutException.class);
   }
   ```

   As we can see, the server doesn't return the response within the defined timeout of 500 ms. As a result, the `OkHttpClient` throws a *SocketTimeoutException*.
4. Write Timeout:

   A write timeout defines a **maximum time of inactivity between two data packets when sending the request to the server**.

   Similarly, as for the connect and read timeouts, **we can override the default value of 10 seconds using** `OkHttpClient.Builder#writeTimeout`. As a convention, a zero value means no timeout at all.

   In the following example, we set a very short write timeout of 10 ms and post a 1 MB content to the server:

   ```
   @Test
   public void whenWriteTimeoutExceeded_thenSocketTimeoutException() {
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         .build();

       Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url("https://httpbin.org/delay/2")
         .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), create1MBString()))
         .build();

       Throwable thrown = catchThrowable(() -> client.newCall(request).execute());

       assertThat(thrown).isInstanceOf(SocketTimeoutException.class);
   }
   ```

Comment: The following statement on that Baeldung page is potentially confusing: "A read timeout is applied from the moment the connection between a client and a target host has been successfully established." After connection, the client sends a request. If the read timeout is "applied from the moment the connection \[is\] established",
then: how is the read timeout applied to the _sending of the request_? My understanding is that the read timeout applies only to the reading of the response, _after_ the request is sent, not "from the moment the connection \[is\] established". Am I missing something?

Comment: Continuing the thread of my previous comment: OkHttp can reuse existing connections. If the read timeout for a call "is applied "(starts?) from "the moment the connection \[is\] established", then that might have been a long time, many calls, ago.